# Procedure to install Plastic-scm package on Ubuntu-12.04 – LTS

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, plasticscm

Could you share the procedure to install Plastic-scm package on Ubuntu-12.04 – LTS.

Actually I have referred the guideline from the below link.

https://www.plasticscm.com/plastic-for-linux/index.html

it worked for Ubuntu-14.04-LTS, So let me know the steps to install in Ubuntu-12.04 – LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the guidelink you can see the next paragraph that I think answers your question:

> Supported versions: We currently support Debian 6, Debian 8 and Ubuntu
>   14.04. However, the Debian 6 repository is compatible with Debian 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 as well.

So you just need to follow the steps for "Debian_6.0".

From the guide:

> ... So, for our public repository, you just need to add the following
>   lines with your favorite text editor (remember that you'll need
>   administrator access since this is a system file), replacing
>    with "Debian_6.0", "Debian_8.1" or "Ubuntu_14.04"
>   (removing quotation marks) depending on your target distribution ...